App Insights Kusto time series chart with series for each severity over time
I have the following query:
union traces, exceptions
| extend TimeSlot = bin(timestamp, 15m)
| summarize count() by TimeSlot, severityLevel

However it produces a chart with a line called _count and another called severityLevel. I would like multiple lines, one for each severity level. Is that even possible?

Try adding the render as barchart as the following
union traces, exceptions
| extend TimeSlot = bin(timestamp, 15m)
| summarize Count = count() by TimeSlot, severityLevel
| make-series Count=avg(Count) on TimeSlot from startofday(now()) to endofday(now()) step 15m by severityLevel
| render barchart


Unfortunately that makes no difference to the data - all it does is make it a line chart. :(

I think I need a way to have either: multiple columns in the source data for each severity level?

I updated my answer ...give it a try

No that's just given me the same values across the day. Not to worry, I gave up in the end and hacked this together:
union traces, exceptions
| where severityLevel > 1
| project
TimeSlot = bin(timestamp, 15m),
IsWarn = severityLevel == 2,
IsError = severityLevel == 3
| summarize Warning = countif(IsWarn), Error = countif(IsError) by TimeSlot
